# SQL Server stored procedure in .NET Core 6 Web API to produce JSON data used in Angular app

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that has an `ID` parameter and returns a string in JSON format that is needed in the Angular app.

Here is a sample of the JSON needed:

```
[
    {
        "type": "date",
        "name": "asofdate",
        "ui": 
        {
            "label": "As Of Date",
            "placeholder": "Enter a date"
        },
        "validators": { "required": "true" }
    },
    {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "scope",
        "ui": { "label": "Scope", "placeholder": "Select a scope" },
        "validators": { "required": "true" },
        "source": [
                     { "value": 1, "text": "ABC" },
                     { "value": 2, "text": "CDE" },
                     { "value": 3, "text": "FGI" }
                  ]
    }
]
```

Here is a what the result of running the stored procedure looks like:

[image]

When I run the Web API passing the ID parameter to the stored procedure, I would like to capture the response as a JSON object to be used in the Angular app.

But the Web API is returning this:

```
[
  {
    "jsonResponse": "[
                      {
                       \"type\":\"date\",
                       \"name\":\"asofdate\",
                       \"ui\":{\"label\":\"As Of Date\",\"placeholder\":\"Enter a date\"},
                       \"validators\":{\"required\":\"true\"}
                      }
                      ,
                      {
                       \"type\":\"select\",
                       \"name\":\"scope\",
                       \"ui\":{\"label\":\"Scope\",\"placeholder\":\"Select a scope\"},
                       \"validators\":{\"required\":\"true\"},
                       \"source\":[{\"value\":1,\"text\":\"ABC\"},{\"value\":2,\"text\":\"DEF\"},{\"value\":3,\"text\":\"GHI\"}]}
  }
]
```

Is there a way to get the JSON response from the Web API without all the `"\"` and without:

```
{
    "jsonResponse": "
```

so that it matches the sample above?

Here is the code from the Web API:

```
[HttpGet("{ReportID}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<usp_ReportParameterResult>>> GetReportParameters(int ReportID)
{
    if (_context.usp_ReportParameterAsync == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var op = new OutputParameter<int>();
    var JSONresponse = await _context.usp_ReportParameterAsync(ReportID, op);

    if (JSONresponse == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return JSONresponse;
}
```

The stored procedure uses `JSON_QUERY` and `JSON PATH` to create the needed nested arrays.

So, in the angular code I have the following hard-coded:

```
  TESTDATA:any[] = [
{
  type:'text',
  name:'firstName',
  validators:{
    required:true
  },
  ui:{label:'First Name',placeholder:'Enter Your First Name'}
}
,
{
  "type":"date",
  "name":"asofdate",
  "ui":{"label":"****As Of Date","placeholder":"Enter a date","class":["date-picker-wrapper"]},
  "validators":{"required":"true"}     
}
```

]

What I need is instead of this data being hrad-coded it is being dynamically generated from a Web API.

The hard-coded data looks like the following from browser debug:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

From the web api data looks like the following:

[image]

It is not an array like the TESTDATA. Is the a way to get response from web api into an array format as required?

Comment: Since you've already got JSON content in the string you've returned from the stored procedure, have you tried to declare your method returns a [ContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and then return [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.content?view=aspnetcore-6.0) with the `application/json` MIME type?

Comment: Hi @HALO, it is a correct json type data and do you meet any problem when use it in Angular app?

Comment: I have not tried to access yet in the Angular app. I will give that a try and see if I encounter any issues.

Comment: I added more information above as the format of the data returned from web api is not in the required format.

Comment: Can you just run the proc directly to ascertain where the escape chars are being introduced?

Comment: See above. The stored procedure results from SSMS does not show escape characters but the results from web api does. I believe its an issue with the [] around the results pushing the data into 1 array element rather that 2 as we can see in the hard-coded TESTDATA.

Comment: actually I modified the stored procedure and it is now returning the data correctly in Angular the only thing now is how to remove the escape characters in the array

Comment: I was able to get the API to return the data like TESTDATA. The only problem is that the UI and validators still have the extra "\". I'm thinking that its a issue on the Web API piece that is calling the stored procedure to create the JSON data. The model for the data sets all values: type, name, validators an ui to string. Validators and UI are not strings. Is there another type I can use on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, easiest solution was to remove the backlashes in the Angular app by simply doing the following:

```
        for (let item of this.formattedJSON) {
        item.ui = JSON.parse(item.ui);
        item.validators = JSON.parse(item.validators);  
    }
```